# how to read content from form array in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have form array which input from user and then i want to read every single element from the form array and insert it into database using the web service but i''m unable to create a method for reading the element singularly . my form array code is as following :-

```
 createskillForm()
    {
      this.skillForm=this.formBuilder.group({
        skills:this.formBuilder.array([this.createskillFeild()])
      });
    }
```

and the create skill feild method is as follows :-

```
  createskillFeild():FormGroup
    {
      return this.formBuilder.group({
        skills:['',Validators.required]
      });
    }
```

please help me out as i'm unable to figure the method out?

Comment: You are not showing anywhere your attempt to `reading the element singularily`? And what specifically does that mean, if I understand you correctly, you mean iterating the formarray?

Comment: @AJT_82 yes exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the form array control like:

```
let myfArr = this.skillForm.get('skills') as FormArray
```

To get all the values from the form array, you could probably use something like:

```
let arrValues = myfArr.controls.map(eachGroup => eachGroup.value);
```

`arrValues` will be an array of values of all the formGroups in the from array.

**Edit**

If you just want to get the values of the form array, you can simply do:

```
this.skillForm.get('skills').value
```